# Update a field based on two tables and most earliest date based on duplicate names

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I have two tables:

- Albums
- Tracks

Albums fields:

- AlbumID
- ArtistID
- AlbumName
- ReleaseDate
- IsFirstRelease

Tracks fields:

- TrackID
- AlbumID
- TrackName

It seems that some `TrackName` (the song) from the exact same `ArtistID` can appear on different albums. Like a complication album, etc..

I am trying to make a query that will find duplicate `TrackName` of the same ArtistID and set to **true** `IsFirstRelease` for the earliest `ReleaseDate`.

Target is to flag the earliest album.

Comment: What happens when an album X contains a song that is also found in an album Y released previously but all the other songs are first released?

Comment: Good point, Actually what are saying is that `IsFirstRelease` should be inside Track table (aka per song) instead of Album table. I can go that way.